# How to get data from a JSON and display as separate in vb6

Tags: json, rest, parsing, vb6

I am getting data from a JSON file and want to display some data individually in a textbox. I am using (VBA-JSON v2.3.1 JsonConverter). VBA-Json on Github). [VBA-Json in Github](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON)

Here is Output :

```
{
"status": "OK",
"code": "OK",
"message": "Ok",
"data": {
"user": {
  "id": 5883,
  "username": "Demo",
  "name": "Niki Jackson",
  "email": "abcd@yahoo.com",
  "mobile": "9325547989",
  "certificate_id": "122876",
  "address": "Sunshine Bvl",
  "company": "Light Co",
  "expire": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  "status": "active"
  }
 }
}
```

I use this code but not work:

```
Dim Parsed As Object
Set Parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(JSONS)
text1.text = Parsed("data")("user")(1)("name")
text2.text = Parsed("data")("user")(1)("mobile")
```

How can I Parse data from Json?
Please, your codes is from the JsonConverter file, not the json file .
Thank you in advance

Comment: For future readers, what did "does not work" mean? Did you get an error message? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, I'll leave it here so that maybe the problem of others can be solved.

```
Dim Parsed As Object
Set Parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(JSONS)
text1.text = Parsed.Item("data").Item("user").Item("name")
text2.text = Parsed.Item("data").Item("user").Item("mobile")
```